# Is it permissible to dye my hair with black henna?

Tags: sharia, hair, dyeing-hair

I have some grey hair. Is it permissible to dye my hair with black henna?

Someone said black henna is permissible, because it doesn't include ammonia (godrej).

Comment: Why would ammonia be *haram* - if that is the correct designation?

Comment: Related: [Can I dye my beard or hair black?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16162)

Answer (score 1):

**Totally, Henna is considered as a profitable matter. hence there mustn't be an obstacle in using it. For instance is has narrated from Muhammad Baqer Majlesi (as a Shia Scholar) that:**

> Whoever uses Henna (to dye..), God will save him from three diseases,
>
> Jozaam (جزام) __ Brs (برص)__ Akelah or Qanqaria (الآکله ام قانقاریا)
>
> {محمدباقر المجلسى (ج 73، ص 89ـ90، 97، 99، 127؛ ] من الکتب الحديثىِ
> ابن بابويه}

**Even there are narrations which mention that:**

> some Imams of Shia used henna …
>
> (Koleini, Osul Kafi, Vol.6, page509) (کلینی، اصول کافی، ج۶، ص۵۰۹.)

Therefore not only it doesn’t mention it as a forbidden issue, but also it has pointed as  a suitable practice by using Henna. Accordingly apparently you could be able to use it.

---

**Reference**:

- [www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%AE%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A8)

Answer (score 0):

Wa alaikum assalam.

Please read these Ahadeeth:

> Jaabir ibn ‘Abdullah reported that Abu Quhaafah was brought on the day
> of the conquest of Makkah, and his head and beard were white like
> "Thaghaamah" (a plant whose flowers and fruit are white). The
> Messenger of Allah (Peace & Blessings of Allah be upon Him) said:
> "Change this with something, but avoid black." (Reported by Muslim,
> no. 3962).
>
> Ibn ‘Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him) said: "The Messenger of
> Allah (Peace & Blessings of Allah be upon Him) said: ‘At the end of
> time there will be people who will dye their hair black like the crops
> of pigeons. They will never even smell the fragrance of Paradise."
> (reported by Imam Ahmad, see also Saheeh al-Jaami‘, no. 8153).
>
> It was also reported from the Prophet (Peace & Blessings of Allah be
> upon Him) that one should change grey hair, using any colour except
> black. Abu Dharr reported that the Prophet (Peace & Blessings of Allah
> be upon Him) said: "The best things with which to change grey hair are
> henna and ‘katam’ (a plant similar to henna which is used as a dye)."
> (Reported by al-Tirmidhi, no. 1675; he said: This is a saheeh Hasan
> Hadith).

So according to these, it is not permissible to use black color as a hair dye. Please read this for details:

- http://islamqa.info/en/476

Comment: Apparently Companions and Tabi‘un didn't understand it in this way. It is reported about Uthman, Hasan and Husain that they would dye their hair black. (mentioned by Nawawi in which commentary on Sahih Muslim)