# Does dying one's beard or hair black play a role in jihad?

Tags: jihad, hair, beard, dyeing-hair

In [Ibn Hajar Haytami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Haytami)'s list of "enormities", item 111 is:

> Dying the beard or hair black for other than jihad or the like.

(Also mentioned at [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/202884).)

**Question**: Does dying one's beard or hair black play a role in jihad?

I'm not sure how reliable this enormity is.  The answers to [Can I dye my beard or hair black?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16162/17163) don't list jihad as an exception to the ruling against dying one's hair and/or beard black.

Comment: I think dying is recommended because it's appealing to women and also it makes men look more formidable during wars

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dying hair black is considered permissible for the purpose of Jihad. This is has been noted in  the writings of the [Hanafis](http://shamela.ws/book/21613/4198), [Malikis](https://archive.org/details/Kivayat_talib/Kivayat_talib04/page/n336/mode/1up), [Shafi'is](https://shamela.ws/book/2186/293#p1) and [Hanbalis](https://shamela.ws/book/21642/70).

> ويستثنى من ذلك المجاهد اتفاقا
>
> A Mujahid is an exception in this ruling by agreement
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3633)</sup>

> أما الخضاب بالسواد للغزو، ليكون أهيب في عين العدو فهو محمود بالاتفاق
>
> As for dyeing hair with black in military expeditions so that it strikes terror in the eyes of the enemy, it is praiseworthy by agreement
>
> <sup>— [Radd al-Muhtar](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/3864)</sup>

The reason is that it gives the illusion that the soldiers of the Muslim army are all in their prime youth which is useful for demoralizing the enemy and causing them fear.

Also refer to my answer on: [Can I dye my beard or hair black?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16162/17163)